# Angular Matrial dialog and datepicker bug [ES6]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, ecmascript-6, angular-material

**first** :

Everythings (souces codes) you need to re-procude the bug is this repository:
https://github.com/darkiron/angular-datepicker-bug

**the probleme :**

On modal dialog I use datepicker (all from material for angular)
th datepicker is open with white screen [image]

this is the probleme. 
**Thanks for your help**

Answer (score 0):

Using bad css : 
replace by the good version (1.1.3) :

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

;)